# Iniciar Desenvolvimento App Resultado Jogos Tabuleiro

Tags: android, html5, websql

Quero desenvolver um **app plataforma android** que gerencie o placar das partidas de jogos de tabuleiro entre meus amigos.
Não sei quase nada sobre **android**, e preciso começar.

Uma das minhas dúvidas é sobre como salvar as informações dos resultados.
Então a minha pergunta é:

Qual é a forma de trabalhar com esse **armazenando de informações**?

Posso usar banco de dados local (do lado do cliente) e distribuir o resultado entre outros celulares? Ou a forma correta é ter um banco de dados em uma hospedagem e concentrar todas as informações nele?

Penso em construir a aplicação usando **html5 e seus novos recursos**.

Comment: Já ouviu falar do phonegap?

Comment: Sim. Desenvolve em HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Comment: exatamente, é uma ótima alternativa, ao invés de fazer direto em android, vc vai ter uma aplicação híbrida e com uma grande quantidade de plugins

Comment: Entendi. Agora quero pelo menos uma ideia sobre salvar as informações.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que escolher qual arquitetura usar.

**Nativo**

Você pode fazer em java android, e utilizar SQLite para salvar as informações, mas o SQLite fica embarcado, se você quiser enviar os dados para criar um ranking online, alem do SQLite vai precisar de uma estrutura WEB que receba os dados e grave.

**Phonegap**

O desenvolvimento com phonegap é muito mais rapido que nativo, da para usar SQLite para guardar dados mesmo offline, porem você pode utilizar arquitetura REST e gravar tudo direto no seu servidor, mas nada impede de utilizar SQLite interno tambem.

**Webresponsivo**

Esse pode ser totalmente web, sem instalar nada no celular do cliente, porem ele pode acessar de diversos devices, vocÊ pode guardar os dados com webstorage do proprio navegador, mas tambem tem que ter mecanismo para gravar o ranking no seu servidor web.

Comment: Muito clara sua resposta. Aguardar se ocorre outra resposta tão boa quanto a sua. Eu quero guardar o ranking, e também penso quando alguém clicar em "iniciar Partida", todos vejam que existe uma partida em andamento. Entende? a interatividade vai existir, por isso minha preocupação em como tratar esse banco de dados.

Comment: Eu faria arquitetura REST com cordova phonegap.